# How to fix all elements when browser window resized

Tags: css, blogger

I've read so many answers to this question but still can't figure out how to stop elements of my blog moving when a browser is resized. I just got a new template and didn't have this problem with my last one.

My site is: [shannondarko.co.uk](http://shannondarko.co.uk)

I'm not sure what section of code to provide you with but I think it might be this part?

```
<b:template-skin>
  <b:variable default='960px' name='content.width' type='length' value='1500px'/>
  <b:variable default='0' name='main.column.left.width' type='length'/>
  <b:variable default='310px' name='main.column.right.width' type='length' value='240px'/>

  <![CDATA[
  body {

    --min-width: $(content.width);

  }

  .content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {

    --min-width: $(content.width);

    max-width: 100%;

    _width: $(content.width);

  }

  .main-inner .columns {

    --padding-left: $(main.column.left.width);

    --padding-right: $(main.column.right.width);

  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {

    left: $(main.column.left.width);

    --right: $(main.column.right.width);

    /* IE6 does not respect left and right together */

    _width: expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth -

        parseInt("$(main.column.left.width)") -

        parseInt("$(main.column.right.width)") + 'px');

  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer {

    width: $(main.column.left.width);

  }

  .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer {

    --width: $(main.column.right.width);

  }

  .main-inner .column-left-outer {

    width: $(main.column.left.width);

    right: 100%;

    margin-left: -$(main.column.left.width);

  }

  .main-inner .column-right-outer {

    --width: $(main.column.right.width);

    --margin-right: -$(main.column.right.width);

  }


  #layout {
    min-width: 0;
  }

  #layout .content-outer {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 800px;
  }

  #layout .region-inner {
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
</b:template-skin>
```

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: Please include resulting HTML/CSS instead of the source (JSP?) file.

Comment: This is what is in my HTML on my site, it's not from the file?

Comment: Are you using Blogger? You might want to update your tags to include 'blogger' (or the relevant platform you're using) and remove 'html' to find a solution faster.